# jquery get on a https url callback not being called - fails silently

Tags: javascript, jquery, https, get

Please see below simple code block that makes a basic jQuery get call

```
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Get test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script>
        // register callback on windows.load
        $( window ).on( "load", loaderfunc );
        // loaderfunc definition
        function loaderfunc (jQuery)
        {
            alert("calling get now");
            $.get('https:/myrestfulservice-get-endpoint.mydomain.net',
                function (data){
                    alert("in callback from get");
                }
                .fail(function (jqXHR,settings,ex) { 
                    alert('failed, '+ ex); 
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    alert("json retrieve success");
                })
            )
        }

</script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1> TEST PAGE FOR GET REQUEST </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

In this I see alert "calling get" on page load.
However thereafter I don't see any alert either  for success or for failure
I did verify that my service at provided url returns a valid http response - that happens to be a json string  ( "https:/myrestfulservice-get-endpoint.mydomain.net" this service name is fudged )

I am open to using getJSON - however that too fails silently
What am I missing

Comment: Your `)` to `$.get` is in the wrong place - it should be `$.get(url, function() {}).fail().done();` but you have `$.get(url, function() {}.fail().done());`   Although that should give you an error in the console, so maybe not copied correctly to the question?

Comment: That is correct - my format was wrong - Thank you - I did not observe the message on console